# Custom pinterest button

Tags: c#, pinterest

I am trying to add a pinterest button to a control. I am trying to add the href in the code behind but it does not seem to be working.

so far i have

```
pinterestButton.Attributes.Add("href", "http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=" + productLink + "&media=" + imageLink);
```

The pinterest window opens up but there no data in it.

Can anyone give me a hand?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to URI-encode the query string parameters, i.e.

`"http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=" + productLink + "&media=" + imageLink`

should be:

`"http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(productLink) + "&media=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(imageLink)`

I'm not an ASP/C# programmer, but a quick lookup shows that this is the correct method for URI-encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what exactly sure what you're looking for your code to do...but paste this code in the place of the url of the pages you want to pin from. Should act as a pin it button.

```
javascript:void((function(){var%20e=document.createElement('script');e.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');e.setAttribute('charset','UTF-8');e.setAttribute('src','http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinmarklet.js?r='+Math.random()*99999999);document.body.appendChild(e)})());
```

Comment: Note, quite some modern browsers no longer accept scripts in the address-bar (if I recall correctly FF started under pressure of FB, so sad...), however they still work as 'bookmarklets' (a fancy bookmark where the url-field holds the script).